# Why WebPack is not present in Visual studio 2017 Dot Net core 2.1 & Angular template?

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

There are so many new things in webpack 4 that i can't list them all like Webpack is so fast up to 98% with less configuration. In Visual Studio 2017 with dot net core + angular 4, they had the webpack in the template but yesterday i have created a new project in VS 2017 with Dot net core 2.1 + angular and i did not found any thing related to webpack. A question roaming in my head that why VS 2017 template has no webpack? Does VS use webpack internally or is there any other methodology better than webpack to build the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS doesn't use web pack internally but angular application use web pack internally and angular-cli is always use latest version of web pack. Just take a look of official github repo https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.

Comment: I meant the template that VS created for angular has no webpack configuration at all.

Comment: yes. I got your point if you create standalone angular application using angular-cli then also application doesn't contain any webpack.config.js in earlier version of angular we have that kind of file. Now they are maintain configuration file internally.

Comment: It means webpack is used internally by angular-cli. Is there any way to see webpack configuration?

Comment: @Umer: Yes, Thats what i am telling you. You just use `ng eject` command to see configuration of webpack.

Comment: Angular 6 doesn't support ng eject.